# Using google API or other APIs for video chatting and store some information in my database

Tags: c#, google-api, video-streaming, webrtc, t4-toolbox

*I wish to develop a video chat application using APIs like google Hangout API or tokBox or any other API, and with using these APIs, I also have some more requirements to be fulfilled.*

**Requirements**

1.Who talked with whom.

2.How much time did any user used video chatting, and may be more.

3.one to one video chat.

4.one to many video chat.

5.user can accept or deny chat request.

6.Public streaming can also be available. but user can restrict them.

7.These informations are needed to be stored in our database against our website userIDs.

How is this possible. Where do I start. We are ready to pay for great live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure but it looks you are looking for something like Talky, aren't you?.

https://talky.io/

It's developed using SimpleWebRTC (OpenSource): https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/SimpleWebRTC
so it's a good starting point.

There are other frameworks and possibilities but the important point is that you can fulfil all your requirements with WebRTC.